# How to reduce the absolute font-size by percent in different view port size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

I am sorry about this crazy question. expecting some idea or workaround. I am in the position to take care of one of the existing webpage to convert it in to mobile view. the web page already added with absolute fonts. example:

```
h2{
  font-size:24px;
}

p{
  font-size:18px
}

li{
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

now I would like to reduce the font size in to 80% of the existing current font size. But i don't want to write them each and every element separately, it will take days and days. is there any way to reduce the font-size from it's current size by percentage. even js ok for me.

like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767){

  .wrapper * {
    font-size: 80%; //let each element applied with it's 80% from original font size.. like so
  }

}
```

Comment: IMO, this is the last thing you should be worried about. By and large, browsers on Phones, laptops and desktops can all zoom/scale the page to the user's desire. So worry about EVERYTHING ELSE before getting to this

Comment: Then don't use `px`, use `rem`. Then adjust the `rem` base value in a media query.

Comment: So if you see the base font size to 18px (as 1rem) then your `h2` would be 1.3rem,

Comment: thiwid I am not sure though, but I don't think that your requirement can be full filled with css only, but this is possible with JS

Comment: @Paulie_D - we can't ask user to use the zoom function. how client will accept it?